# Git: How to work with two remote branches?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I am using **git svn** to work with two remote branches "trunk" and "branch1" in a **SVN repository**.

**Checks are supposed to go to "branch1" and then merged to "trunk".**

I have set up .git/config to track both trunk and branch1.

[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn+ssh://svn.aaa.com/data/svn/repos/Code/trunk
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
[svn-remote "svn-branch1"]
    url = svn+ssh://svn.aaa.com/data/svn/repos/Code/branches/branch1
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn-branch1

I have my local **master** branch pointing to trunk and **master1** pointing to branch1.

Here is how I do my development checkins:

1. git co master1 -b feature1
2. git commit
3. git svn dcommit
4. git co master
5. git cherry-pick -x <....>
6. git svn dcommit
7. git br -d feature1

I always get the error saying "**the branch is not fully merged**". Of course, that branch is pointing to the remote branch1, not trunk, so I have to do a force delete.

Is this how this should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the intended behaviour for `git branch -d` to avoid accidentally deleting branches that you haven’t merged yet (using `git merge`). Downgrading git to Subversion’s level of braindeadness forces you to use some workarounds, unfortunately; this is one of them. Use `git branch -D` and start counting the days left until you finally get rid of Subversion. :)